# Loop through array in JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, api

I have created a loop to cycle through the information in an API with [this endpoint](http://api.quran.com:3000/api/v3/search?q=allah&size=20&page=0&language=en):

That returns data in this format (reduced in order to simplify):

```json
{
    "query": "allah",
    "total_count": 3394,
    "took": 153,
    "current_page": 1,
    "total_pages": 170,
    "per_page": 20,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 664,
            "verse_number": 171,
            "chapter_id": 4,
            "verse_key": "4:171",
            "text_madani": "يَا أَهْلَ الْكِتَابِ لَا تَغْلُوا فِي دِينِكُمْ وَلَا تَقُولُوا عَلَى اللَّهِ إِلَّا الْحَقَّ ۚ إِنَّمَا الْمَسِيحُ عِيسَى ابْنُ مَرْيَمَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ وَكَلِمَتُهُ أَلْقَاهَا إِلَىٰ مَرْيَمَ وَرُوحٌ مِّنْهُ ۖ فَآمِنُوا بِاللَّهِ وَرُسُلِهِ ۖ وَلَا تَقُولُوا ثَلَاثَةٌ ۚ انتَهُوا خَيْرًا لَّكُمْ ۚ إِنَّمَا اللَّهُ إِلَٰهٌ وَاحِدٌ ۖ سُبْحَانَهُ أَن يَكُونَ لَهُ وَلَدٌ ۘ لَّهُ مَا فِي السَّمَاوَاتِ وَمَا فِي الْأَرْضِ ۗ وَكَفَىٰ بِاللَّهِ وَكِيلًا",
            "words": [
                {
                    "id": 82924,
                    "position": 1,
                    "text_madani": "يَا أَهْلَ",
                    "text_indopak": null,
                    "text_simple": "يا اهل",
                    "verse_key": "4:171",
                    "class_name": "p105",
                    "line_number": 1,
                    "page_number": 105,
                    "code": "&#xfb51;",
                    "code_v3": "&#xfb51;",
                    "char_type": "word",
                    "audio": {
                        "url": "//verses.quran.com/wbw/004_171_001.mp3"
                    },
                    "translation": {
                        "id": 72752,
                        "language_name": "english",
                        "text": "O People",
                        "resource_name": null,
                        "resource_id": 59
                    },
                    "transliteration": {
                        "id": 72752,
                        "language_name": "english",
                        "text": "O People",
                        "resource_name": null,
                        "resource_id": 59
                    },
                    "highlight": null
                }
            ],
            "translations": [
                {
                    "resource_name": "Abdullah Muhammad Basmeih",
                    "text": "dan janganlah kamu mengatakan sesuatu terhadap <em class=\"hlt1\">Allah</em> melainkan yang benar; sesungguhnya Al Masih Isa",
                    "id": 217603,
                    "language_name": "malay",
                    "resource_id": 39
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

It goes through the array of results and displays each one in an `<li>` tag. Then it goes through the translations. The following snippet displays only the first element of array, I want to include a new list inside my list item (right after the verse key) with all the translations inside more `<li>` tags. Is there any way to do this?

The snippet:

```js
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    count = data.total_count;
    took = data.took;
    results = data.results;
    
    var li = '';
    results = data.results;
    var li = '';
    for (const x of results) {
        
        li +=
        '<li>' +
        x.text_madani +
        '<br><span class="surah">' +
        x.translations[0].text +' - '+ x.translations[0].resource_name+
        '</span><br> <span class="surah">' +
        x.verse_key +
        '</span><br></li>';
    }

    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = li;

    document.getElementById('Results').innerHTML =
        'Results: ' + count + '';
    document.getElementById('Time').innerHTML =
        'Took: ' + took + ' milliseconds to load ' + count + ' results';
})
```

here's all the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
    />
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"
    ></script>
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Google+Sans+Display:wght@300;400;700;800;900&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: 'Google Sans Display', sans-serif;
      }
      em{
        font-weight:900;
        font-style: normal;
      }
      li {
        font-size: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 4vh;
        font-weight: 400;

      }
      .content {

        margin-left: 20vw;
        margin-right: 20vw;
        text-align: justify;
      }
      :root {
  --primary: #23adad;
  --greyLight: #23adade1;
  --greyLight-2: #cbe0dd;
  --greyDark: #2d4848;
}



ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.items-list {
  max-width: 90vw;
  margin: 2rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 3rem;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .items-list {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
}

.item {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: var(--greyDark);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.item span {
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 0.8rem 2rem rgba(90, 97, 129, 0.05);
  border-radius: 0.6rem;
  padding: 2rem;
  font-size: 3rem;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.item:hover span {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  color: var(--primary);
}
.item p {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  color: var(--greyLight);
}

.page {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 5rem;
  margin: 3rem;
  border-radius: 0.6rem;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 0.8rem 2rem rgba(90, 97, 129, 0.05);
}
.page__numbers, .page__btn, .page__dots {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0.8rem;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.page__dots {
  width: 2.6rem;
  height: 2.6rem;
  color: var(--greyLight);
  cursor: initial;
}
.page__numbers {
  width: 2.6rem;
  height: 2.6rem;
  border-radius: 0.4rem;
}
.page__numbers:hover {
  color: var(--primary);
}
.page__numbers.active {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: var(--primary);
  font-weight: 600;
  border: 1px solid var(--primary);
}
.page__btn {
  color: var(--greyLight);
  pointer-events: none;
}
.page__btn.active {
  color: var(--greyDark);
  pointer-events: initial;
}
.page__btn.active:hover {
  color: var(--primary);
}

    </style>
<div class="content">
    <h3 id="Results"></h3>
    <h3 id="Time"></h3>
    <h6 id="demo"></h6>
  </div>
  <div id="app" class="container">  
    <ul class="page">
        <li class="page__btn"><span class="material-icons">chevron_left</span></li>
        <li class="page__numbers"> 1</li>
        <li class="page__numbers active">2</li>
        <li class="page__numbers">3</li>
        <li class="page__numbers">4</li>
        <li class="page__numbers">5</li>
        <li class="page__numbers">6</li>
        <li class="page__dots">...</li>
        <li class="page__numbers"> 10</li>
        <li class="page__btn"><span class="material-icons">chevron_right</span></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <script>
      window.onload = function () {
        var search = prompt('search');
        var arText;
        var enText;
        var surah;
        var ayahNumber;
        var surahAndAyah;
        $(document).ready(function () {
          getQuote();
          $('#shuffle').on('click', getQuote);
          $('#tweet').click(function () {
            var tweetLink = '' + '"' + enText + '" QS' + surahAndAyah;
            window.open(tweetLink);
          });
        });

        function getQuote() {
          var ayah = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6236) + 1;
          var url =
            'http://api.quran.com:3000/api/v3/search?q= ' +
            search +
            ' &size=20&page=0&language=en';

          arText;
          enText;
          surah;
          ayahNumber;
          surahAndAyah;

          $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
            count = data.total_count;
            took = data.took;
            results = data.results;
            
            var li = '';
            results = data.results;
            var li = '';
            for (const x of results) {
              
              li +=
                '<li>' +
                x.text_madani +
                '<br><span class="surah">' +
                x.translations[0].text +' - '+ x.translations[0].resource_name+
                '</span><br> <span class="surah">' +
                x.verse_key +
                '</span><br></li>';
            }

            document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = li;

            document.getElementById('Results').innerHTML =
              'Results: ' + count + '';
            document.getElementById('Time').innerHTML =
              'Took: ' + took + ' milliseconds to load ' + count + ' results';
          })
            .done(function () {
              console.log('second success');
            })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              //alert("You're offline! " + textStatus);
            })
            .always(function () {
              console.log('complete');
            });
        }
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you please share how is data looks like from your api?

Comment: it's here https://quran.api-docs.io/v3/search/8zmA9uBcdWsDXgqQR

Comment: You want the `<li>` after your current `<li>`? Or just to multiply the results based on the translations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by looping through both the `results` and `translations` keys, something like this:

```js
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
  count = data.total_count;
  took = data.took;
  results = data.results;
  
  var li = '';
  results = data.results;
  for (const x of results) {
      li += '<li>' + x.text_madani + '<br>' +
        '<span class="surah">' + x.verse_key + '</span><ul>'
    for (const y of x.translations) {
      li += '<li><span class="surah">' + 
        y.text +' - '+ y.resource_name+
      '</span></li>';
    }
    li += '</ul></li>';
  }

  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = li;

  document.getElementById('Results').innerHTML =
    'Results: ' + count + '';
  document.getElementById('Time').innerHTML =
    'Took: ' + took + ' milliseconds to load ' + count + ' results';
})
```

Please keep in mind that this might mess with your HTML if your data is not sanitized or if it's not using some kind of abstraction to generate the HTML.

Creating HTML using a string concatenated from results from a API is not encouraged.

Comment: doesn't work, updated the question to show all code

Comment: @NinjaSauce I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish. Check [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64235026/loop-through-array-in-json/64235202?noredirect=1#comment113588285_64235026) please

Comment: I want it to loop through the array of translations and display its contents in a list right after verse key

Comment: @NinjaSauce something like this?

Comment: One last thing, translations come in multiple languages, any way I can filter them to a specific language, say English? The translations array does come with a language id. Anyway, you can filter to show only English translations. Sorry, I'm asking too much. I'm new to learning JSON and I'm learning on the way

Comment: Sure, you just need to add a `if` statement inside your loop, something like `if (y. language_name != 'english') continue;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222623/discussion-between-gustavo-kawamoto-and-ninjasauce).

Answer (score 0):

you can create a new ul element and use `insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', str)` in order to append the text as HTML element.

```
function printTranslations(translations) {
  var ul = '<ul>';

  for (const text of translations) {
    ul +=
      '<li><span class="surah">' + 
         text.text + ' - ' + text.resource_name +
       '</span></li>';
  }

  return ul + '</ul>';
}

function (data) {
  count = data.total_count;
  took = data.took;
  results = data.results;

  var ul = document.createElement('ul');
  results = data.results;
  for (const x of results) {

    ul.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
      '<li>' +
      x.text_madani +
      '<br><span class="surah">' +
      printTranslations(x.translations) +
      '<span class="surah">' +
      x.verse_key +
      '</span><br></li>');
  }

  document.getElementById('demo').appendChild(ul);

  document.getElementById('Results').innerHTML = 'Results: ' + count + '';
  document.getElementById('Time').innerHTML =
    'Took: ' + took + ' milliseconds to load ' + count + ' results';
}
```

Comment: doesn't work, updated the question to show all code

Comment: I fixed it a bit but it would help if you could tell what was the error you got

Comment: It doesn't do anything differant. Still one translation. I want it to display all the objects in the array of translations in a list